# Using a stationary data set with exponential smoothing

Tags: feature-selection, exponential-smoothing, stationarity

I am doing time series forecasting and running `Holts Method`  with several variations.(exponential, damped, simple)

```
> dput(tsOenb)
structure(c(142.8163942, 143.5711365, 145.3485827, 142.0577145, 
139.4326176, 140.1236581, 138.6560282, 136.405036, 133.9337229, 
133.8785538, 132.0608441, 130.0866307, 120.1320237, 119.6368882, 
114.3312943, 117.5084111, 114.4960017, 112.9124518, 112.8185478, 
112.3047916, 106.632639, 106.2107158, 106.8455028, 106.3879556, 
104.3451786, 102.9085952, 101.0967783, 101.7858278, 101.0749044, 
102.6441976, 102.0666152, 100, 97.14084104, 97.49972913, 96.91453836, 
96.05132443, 94.98057971, 92.78373451, 92.67526281, 91.82430571, 
91.4153859, 89.51740671, 89.01587176, 84.62259911, 91.48598494, 
89.12053042, 90.02364352, 90.92496121, 89.42963565, 91.93886583, 
88.83918306, 90.39513509, 87.54571761, 91.3386451, 87.7836994, 
91.79178376, 87.56903138, 87.77875755, 89.29938784), .Tsp = c(2000.25, 
2014.75, 4), class = "ts")
> 
> fit1 <- ses(tsOenb)
> fit2 <- holt(tsOenb)
> fit3 <- holt(tsOenb,exponential=TRUE)
> fit4 <- holt(tsOenb,damped=TRUE)
> fit5 <- holt(tsOenb,exponential=TRUE,damped=TRUE)
> # Results for first model:
> fit1$model
ETS(A,N,N) 

Call:
 ses(x = tsOenb) 

  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 0.8877 

  Initial states:
    l = 142.9174 

  sigma:  2.6638

     AIC     AICc      BIC 
360.1846 360.3989 364.3397 
> accuracy(fit1) # training set
                    ME     RMSE    MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set -1.026978 2.663777 1.9862 -0.937466 1.916168 0.4448575 -0.2346051
> accuracy(fit1,tsOenb) # test set
Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : 'start' value not changed
> 
> plot(fit2$model$state)
> plot(fit4$model$state)
> 
> plot(fit3, type="o", ylab="Rental Price Index(hundreds)",
+      flwd=1, plot.conf=FALSE)
> lines(window(tsOenb,start=2000),type="o")
Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : 'start' Wert nicht geändert
> lines(fit1$mean,col=2)
 > lines(fit2$mean,col=3)
> lines(fit4$mean,col=5)
 > lines(fit5$mean,col=6)
> legend("topright", lty=1, pch=1, col=1:6,
+        c("Data","SES","Holt's","Exponential",
+          "Additive Damped","Multiplicative Damped"))
>
```

As you can see I get a forecast using this data set.

[image]

However, the time series is stationary and changing the time series to non stationary gives me errors.

```
> dput(tsOenb)
structure(c(1.0227039, -5.0683144, 0.6657713, 3.3161374, -2.1586704, 
-0.7833623, -0.2203209, 2.416144, -1.7625406, -0.1565037, -7.9803936, 
9.4594715, -4.8104584, 8.4827107, -6.1895262, 1.4288595, 1.4896459, 
-0.4198522, -5.1583964, 5.2502294, 1.0567102, -1.0923342, -1.5852298, 
0.6061936, -0.3752335, 2.5008664, -1.3999729, 2.2802166, -2.1468756, 
-1.4890328, -0.79254376, 3.21804705, -0.94407886, -0.27802316, 
-0.20753079, -1.12610048, 2.0883735, -0.7424854, 0.44203729, 
-1.48905938, 1.39644424, -3.8917377, 11.25665848, -9.22884035, 
3.26856762, -0.00179541, -2.39664325, 4.00455574, -5.60891295, 
4.6556348, -4.40536951, 6.64234497, -7.34787319, 7.56303006, 
-8.23083674, 4.43247855, 1.31090412, 1.0227039, -5.0683144), .Tsp = c(2000.25, 
2014.75, 4), class = "ts")
> 
> fit1 <- ses(tsOenb)
> fit2 <- holt(tsOenb)
> fit3 <- holt(tsOenb,exponential=TRUE)
Error in ets(x, "MMN", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, damped = damped, opt.crit = "mse") : 
  Inappropriate model for data with negative or zero values
> fit4 <- holt(tsOenb,damped=TRUE)
> fit5 <- holt(tsOenb,exponential=TRUE,damped=TRUE)
Error in ets(x, "MMN", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, damped = damped, opt.crit = "mse") : 
  Inappropriate model for data with negative or zero values
> # Results for first model:
> fit1$model
ETS(A,N,N) 

Call:
 ses(x = tsOenb) 

  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 1e-04 

  Initial states:
    l = -0.0558 

  sigma:  4.2163

     AIC     AICc      BIC 
414.3730 414.5873 418.5281 
> accuracy(fit1) # training set
                       ME     RMSE      MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.0001774118 4.216345 3.145087 45.47386 146.8709 0.8467864 -0.7332704
> accuracy(fit1,tsOenb) # test set
Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : 'start' value not changed
> 
> plot(fit2$model$state)
> plot(fit4$model$state)
> 
> plot(fit3, type="o", ylab="Rental Price Index(hundreds)",
+      flwd=1, plot.conf=FALSE)
> lines(window(tsOenb,start=2000),type="o")
Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : 'start' Wert nicht geändert
> lines(fit1$mean,col=2)
 > lines(fit2$mean,col=3)
> lines(fit4$mean,col=5)
 > lines(fit5$mean,col=6)
> legend("topright", lty=1, pch=1, col=1:6,
+        c("Data","SES","Holt's","Exponential",
+          "Additive Damped","Multiplicative Damped"))
```

Hence, is it non-mandatory to clean a data set for stationary using exponential smoothing methods? Why? What are the advantages/disadvantages of using non-stationary data in time series analysis?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I can think no advantage for non stationary data. All books (and answers here on SE) I have read tells one thing: do not use non stationary data, you have no idea what will happen

Comment: @Repmat Thx for your reply! Would you be so kind to point out some questions regarding using stationary data with exponential smoothing. Thx in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76696/non-stationary-time-series-forecasting .  I do not know what you are doing to make the data non-stationary, but it doesn't sound like a good idea to transform data from  a stationary to non-stationary series.  Rather, it would seem more appropriate to use one of the many other time series models available which assume stationary (i.e. mean reversion, ARMA and so forth).  Furthermore, what makes you think your series is stationary?