# Are the forecasting methods like mean, naive, drift, weighted average applicable to non stationary time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, arima

Like AR, MA models essentially need the series to be stationary, do the other forecast methods mentioned above also follow stationary?

Comment: This should help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76696/non-stationary-time-series-forecasting

Answer (score 0):

I would not classify all of those things as "methods", at least not in the same sense as AR and MA. A Naive forecast could be done in many ways; it is a principle, that forecast accuracy shouldn't be evaluated in a vacuum but rather should be evaluated within a forecast value added framework, comparing each forecasting step back to a "naive approach" and ensuring that the increase in accuracy (if any) is worth the time/energy/money it costs to create the forecast.

As @Nishad's link indicates there are forecasting methods that can be used with non-stationary data; therefore, one should utilize a naive forecast. The phrases in your question are all things that might be done as a naive forecast. If the data is not stationary, this might inform your choice of what makes a suitable naive forecast (it shouldn't be "too naive"-- what's the best easy forecast to produce).